# Return my svg polygon

Tags: svg

I have svg with polygon. From right (top) to left (bottom - (100px I think). I want to return this - from left top to right bottom.

```html
<svg class="ddd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="100 0 100 10 0 10" />
</svg>
```

I tried change the numbers on different ways but still not work.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `points` attribute contains pairs of X and Y coordinates.  So your polygon contains three coordinates.

In SVGs, (0, 0) is the top left of the image, and since your shape is 100 x 10, (100,10) would be at the bottom-right.

(100, 0) is the top right point of your triangle (X=100, Y=0)
(100, 10) is the bottom right
(0, 10) is the bottom left

All you would need to do to make top edge of the triangle go from top left to bottom right would be to move the X coordinate of the first point from X=100 to X=0.

I.e. from (100, 0) to (0, 0).

```html
<svg class="ddd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <polygon points="0 0 100 10 0 10" />
</svg>
```